# Only first two sender.tag is working for section header in table view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a table view inside which I am calling multiple nib as row under section

// MARK:- EXTENSIONS TABLE VIEWS

*

```
extension HomeController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 9
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableCellConstants.hHeaderCell) as! HomeHeaderCell
        headerCell.viewAllBtn.tag = section
        headerCell.viewAllBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.viewAll), for: .touchUpInside)
        headerView.addSubview(headerCell)
        return headerView
        
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if indexPath.section == 4{
            guard let cell = self.productTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableCellConstants.trendingProductCell, for: indexPath) as? TrendingCell else{
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            return cell
        }
        
        else if indexPath.section == 5{
            guard let cell = self.productTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableCellConstants.featureCell, for: indexPath) as? FeatureBrandCell else{
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            return cell
            
        }else if indexPath.section == 6{
            guard let cell = self.productTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableCellConstants.spotlightCell, for: indexPath) as? StoplightTableCell else{
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            return cell
        }
        
        guard let cell = self.productTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableCellConstants.momentCell, for: indexPath) as? PriviewProductCell else{
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        return cell
        
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        if indexPath.section == 4{
            return 310
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 5{
            return 200
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 6{
            return 320
        }
        else{
            return 210
        }
    }
}
```

- 

this is button action

```
@objc  func viewAll(sender: UIButton){
        
        print(sender.tag)
        
    }
```

when I click on view all Button only first two section is working that means output is only 0 and 1 tags, remaining section button action not even working, I even put breakpoint nothing is coming on it, not only this even horizontal scroll is not working on collection view that I have under table view which
is under scroll view

Comment: Why you are adding Table Cells into Header Views? I don't think this is right.

Comment: You code looks totally fine even its not the best practice. Try to give background colors to ur cells.

Comment: has done that also not working even I tried to give custom button on view programatically header of using cell its still working for first two only

Answer (score 0):

I'm am not sure to what you did wrong in your code, however I created a test project to try and sort your issue out and I believe I have managed to do so.

My best guess at where you went wrong was either something to do with the `UIButton`'s connection being made from interface builder to code. Or to do with how you specified which cells should be at which row and in which section, inside of the `cellForRowAt` method (I'll look at your code in more detail and update this if I find why your code was not working).

Heres the code in its entirety which worked for me:

**View Controller:**

> NOTE: I changed the `if` statement blocks to a `switch` statement as I
> thought it would make it easier to read, also as I did not have the
> xib files you were using for the cells I created my own basic header
> cell, I then used the basic preset table view cell for the cells
> contained within each section. If you have not worked with `switch`
> statements before, then I recommend you check out the section on them
> in the swift language guide book:
> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID127

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    // MARK:: Life-Cycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.register(HeaderTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: HeaderTableViewCell.id)
    }
    
    // MARK: Button Actions
    
    @objc func viewAll(sender: UIButton){
        print(sender.tag)
    }
    
    // MARK: Data Source
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 9
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: HeaderTableViewCell.id) as! HeaderTableViewCell
        headerCell.viewAllBtn.tag = section
        headerCell.viewAllBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewAll), for: .touchUpInside)
        headerView.addSubview(headerCell)
        return headerView
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 4:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Section 4"
            return cell
        case 5:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Section 5"
            return cell
        case 6:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Section 6"
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Unknown Section (Default)"
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 4:
            return 310
        case 5:
            return 200
        case 6:
            return 320
        default:
            return 210
        }
    }
}
```

**HeaderTableViewCell Cell xib**
[image: HeaderTableViewCell xib screenshot]

**HeaderTableViewCell Code**

```
class HeaderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var headerTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var viewAllBtn: UIButton!
    
    static let id = "HeaderTableViewCell"
    
    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "HeaderTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

> NOTE: Please also be aware that it probably would be a better idea for you to of just used a custom `UIView` instead of a custom `UITableViewCell` for your table view headers.

Comment: I did what you told, I even replace cell from header and made a custom button programatically, still its same, what I think this can be a issue because I'm putting table view inside scroll view and in some row I have collection view inside table view

Answer (score 0):

As i said I had collection view as row inside table view and that table view inside scroll view, so at last I removed scroll view from main view and kept all UI under table view now it working fine

Swift compiler get confused when we have three scrolling view working together so better avoid this, it is not best approach

Thanks @demented07 for your efforts

Comment: In Apple’s human Interface guidelines they advise to never place a scroll view inside of another scroll view. I believe what you’ve said is why.